# How to get API post request with json data

Tags: node.js, api, post, request

I'm triyng to make an API request using postman and body raw data, but I can't read the data on server side.

My request:
http://prntscr.com/n38hes

http://prntscr.com/n38hq9

I've already tried:

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query)
  })
```

and:

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
  })
```

but both of them prints `{}`

I would like to obtain the username and the password for the request I made using postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have body parser configured.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    //here app is express app
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Paulo In your example, you have described 2 approaches. Do you have both them in running code? or you are trying one at a time?

Comment: I'm trying one at a time, but I tested both approaches

Comment: try to add this line as well - app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Make sure that they are added exactly after creating object of express app object